# If, elsif, else: Limitations? Liquid

Tags: javascript, php, css, shopify, liquid

Trying to create an `if`, `elseif` statement using the [Liquid Templating Ruby engine](http://liquidmarkup.org/) It appears to be coded correctly but I am not experiencing the results I am expecting.

Im expecting when a user clicks on a collection (MLB, NBA, etc) the `{% collection.handle` contains `"mlb" %}` will trigger and its respective code block will come into play.

Is there anything that jumps out to anyone as incorrect with this if statement?

```
<div class="carousel-wrap">

<!-- College Slider -->

{% if page.handle or collection.handle contains "collegiate" %}
<div style="margin-bottom:10px;" class="teams-carousel clearfix" id="ncaa-carousel">
<ul class="items clearfix">
    {% for link in linklists.team-carousel.links %}
        <li>
            {% capture src %}team-{{ link.title | handleize }}.png{% endcapture %}
            <a href="{{ link.url }}" style="background-image: url('{{ src | asset_url }}');"></a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
</div>

{% elsif collection.current_type or collection.handle contains "mlb" %}

<!-- MLB Slider -->


<div style="margin-bottom: 10px; display: block !important;" class="teams-carousel" id="mlb-carousel">
<ul class="items clearfix">
    {% for link in linklists.mlb.links %}
        <li>
            {% capture src %}team-{{ link.title | handleize }}.png{% endcapture %}
            <a href="{{ link.url }}" style="background-image: url('{{ src | asset_url }}');"></a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
</div>

{% elsif collection.current_type or collection.handle contains "nba" %}

<!-- NBA Slider -->

<div style="margin-bottom:10px;" class="teams-carousel clearfix" id="nba-carousel">
<ul class="items clearfix">
{% for link in linklists.nba-team-carousel.links %}
        <li>
            {% capture src %}team-{{ link.title | handleize }}.png{% endcapture %}
            <a href="{{ link.url }}" style="background-image: url('{{ src | asset_url }}');"></a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
</div>

{% elsif collection.current_type or collection.handle contains "nhl" %}

<!-- NHL Slider -->

<div style="margin-bottom:10px;" class="teams-carousel clearfix" id="nhl-carousel">
<ul class="items clearfix">
    {% for link in linklists.nhl.links %}
        <li>
            {% capture src %}team-{{ link.title | handleize }}.png{% endcapture %}
            <a href="{{ link.url }}" style="background-image: url('{{ src | asset_url }}');"></a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
</div>

{% elsif collection.current_type or collection.handle contains "mls" %}

<!-- MLS Slider -->

<div style="margin-bottom:10px;" class="teams-carousel clearfix" id="mls-carousel">
<ul class="items clearfix">
    {% for link in linklists.mls.links %}
        <li>
            {% capture src %}team-{{ link.title | handleize }}.png{% endcapture %}
            <a href="{{ link.url }}" style="background-image: url('{{ src | asset_url }}');"></a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
</div> 

{% endif %}
</div>
```

Comment: *"I am not experiencing the results I am expecting..."* Well, what did you expect, and what is happening?

Comment: I am working on http://cirrusfitness.com and I was trying to make it so when a user clicks on a certain collection (MLB, NBA) they are shown the code block (slider) contained in the if statement.. currently only seems to work for MLB.. EX If {% collection.handle contains "nba" %} then show nba sldier

Comment: Good, integrate that into your question (without the website, that's not really necessary). Also make sure to show any errors, research, etc. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Liquid is an open-source, Ruby-based template language created by Shopify.

Comment: @AndyM To see info about tags, hover over them and click on "info". (or if you can't hover, tap them and then tap on "learn more".

Comment: I understand that, Mr Lister, and it really has nothing to do with my comment. Any time a specific library is used, it shouldn't just be mentioned, it should have a link or explanation of what it is, to help people who might want to answer. Especially if a quick Google search doesn't bring up a definite answer.

Comment: What `collection.handle` looks like ? what are `page.handle` and `collection.current_type` ?

Answer (score 0):

> Im expecting when a user clicks on a collection (MLB, NBA, etc) the {%
>   collection.handle contains "mlb" %} will trigger and its respective
>   code block will come into play.

and

> I was trying to make it so when a user clicks on a certain collection
>   (MLB, NBA) they are shown the code block (slider) contained in the if
>   statement

make me think that you want content to display when a user clicks (on something). If that's the case, you're going to need JavaScript, not Liquid. Liquid evaluates (everything) and generates a **static** page. The page (effectively) doesn't change after you hit "save". So Liquid content can't be appearing and disappearing.

However, you can show/hide this content very easily with JavaScript using [JQuery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp).